# How can I retrieve the HTML of this particular div

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML response .

```
<div id="69" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
   <div style="" class="Topping-details" id="69">
      <section id="topping_tsection_69">
         <i id="topping-close"></i>
         <aside>
            <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      1</h6>
            <img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
            <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69" class="tpActive">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
            <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69" class="tpActive">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
         </aside>
         <aside>
            <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      2</h6>
            <img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
            <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69" class="tpActive">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
            <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
         </aside>
         <aside>
            <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      3</h6>
            <img src="images/arrow-topping.png">
            <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
            <section class="secclass"><a data-id="69">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a></section>
         </aside>
      </section>
   </div>
</div>
```

Could anybody please let me know how I can retrieve the details of class Topping-details of id 69?

I tried this way

```
var id_attr_val = 69;
var html = $('.activateUiHTML#'+id_attr_val' .Topping-details').html();
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. You have used `id="69"` multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Three issues there.

The first is that you're using `id="69"` on more than one element. You can't do that, `id` values **must** be unique. So the `id` on the outer div and the `id` on the inner div must be different.

The second is that you're missing a `+` in forming your string.

The third is that forming an `id` selector for `id`s that start with digits is a real pain:

The simplest answer is to change it so the `id` doesn't start with a digit. Perhaps `outer69` and `inner69`.

But if you can't change it, once you've removed the duplicate, you can use an escape. The escaped version of `#69` is `#\36\39`, and of course to actually put backslashes into a string, you have to escape them. So:

```
var id_attr_val = "\\36\\39"; // This is the escape for the id "69"
var html = $('.activateUiHTML#'+id_attr_val).find(".Topping-details").html();
alert(html);
```

Note that I also separated the lookup of the outer element with the `id` from finding the toppings within it. This was purely because the descendant selector didn't work for some reason.

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WrGyE/1/)

Of course, since `id` values must be unique, if you remove the `id` from the inner element, then you can avoid using a CSS selector:

```
var id_attr_val = "69";
var html = $(document.getElementById(id_attr_val)).find(".Topping-details").html();
alert(html);
```

Since `getElementById` doesn't accept a selector, you avoid the problem of escaping it.

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WrGyE/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 html elements with the same ID tag defined. You have to change the code to something like this:

```
<div id="theId" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
   <div style="" class="Topping-details">
       ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Now you can use `$('.activateUiHTML#' + 'theId' + ' .Topping-details').html()`

This should give you the HTML content of the .Topping-details div :)

Also consider not using digits for IDs (at least not as the first character).

Answer (score 0):

Use `rel` insetead of `id` and select by

`$('.Topping-details','.activateUiHTML[rel="'+id_attr_val.toString()+'"]').html();`...

Please note that you have syntax error in your selector, should be

`$('.activateUiHTML#'+id_attr_val.toString()+' .Topping-details').html();`

(`+` was missing and int was not casted to string)

If you don't want to cast int to string, because for example you aquire it from `input`, simply remove `.toString()`... but then, if you declare it manually, make it this way:

`var id_attr_val = "69";`